# Datagrid column width binding to another column in another datagrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a requirement to keep all the column widths matching accross several datagrids. As I have things defined the column can grow as required as the user enters larger numbers. As this happens the sibling table columns get out of alighment and their width needs to keep pace with the column where the data is being entered. Because of the number of columns I can't really use fixed width, although that may be the only way.

Here is a stripped down defination of the datagrid for example. All table are defined in the same fashion and of course have many more columns. Any ideas would be appriciated.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource BaseAFGrid}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="gridBilanActif" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="5,5,0,0">
<DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="False" Header="Nom" Width="260" CanUserSort="False" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <TextBox Margin="{Binding Level, Converter={StaticResource LevelConverter}}" 
                x:Name="txtTitreA" Style="{StaticResource AFTextbox}" 
                IsReadOnly="{Binding TitreEstNonmodifiable}" 
                Text="{Binding Nom, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
                Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn   IsReadOnly="False" Header="1" Width="Auto" MinWidth="55"  CanUserSort="False" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <TextBox  x:Name=" colPeriode1A" Style="{StaticResource MilierDoubleTextBoxAF}" 
                CValidation:TextboxValidator.IsFloating="True" CValidation:TextboxValidator.MaxDecimal="2"
                IsReadOnly="{Binding HasChildren}"  TextChanged="colPeriode1A_TextChanged" 
                Text="{Binding P1_Bilan, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, 
                Converter={StaticResource CurrencyConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn  IsReadOnly="False" Header="2" Width="Auto" MinWidth="55" CanUserSort="False" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <TextBox  x:Name=" colPeriode2A" Style="{StaticResource MilierDoubleTextBoxAF}"
                CValidation:TextboxValidator.IsFloating="True" CValidation:TextboxValidator.MaxDecimal="2"  
                IsReadOnly="{Binding HasChildren}" 
                Text="{Binding P2_Bilan, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, 
                Converter={StaticResource CurrencyConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Bind to a (shared) width property for each column.

Comment: Interesting idea I'll explore it a bit. Thanks